# Is it possible to send a custom object with an Intent as an Extra

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm asking this question: instread of giving a string, a int and so on, can we push a custom object during the creation fo a new Intent?

```
newActivity.PutExtra("JsonDataResult", business.getJSON());
```

In fact I have one object constructed thanks to a JSON (from webrequest) , I parse it and I put it on an object.

At this point I'm passing the string returned from the webrequest to another intent but the parsing takes a long time tu be done, so it could be super-cool the ability to pass custom object with intent.

**EDIT :** I'm using monodroid / xamarin, so

Android.OS.IParcelable cannot be implemented,
Java.IO.ISerializable cannot be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can either let your custom classes implement `Parcelable` (Google says its faster, but you have to do more coding) or  `Serializable`. 
Then add your objects to a bundle (or to the "extra"):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle()
b.putParcelable("myObject",myObject);
b.putSerializable("myObject",myObject);
```

For info to `Parcelable`checkout [this](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)

And if you're interested in the difference between `Parcelable`  and  `Serializable` in more detail check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550670/benefit-of-using-parcelable-instead-of-serializing-object)

I personally prefer the usage of `Serializable` for simple object-passing, since the code ist not spoiled with so much code.

Edit: ok isn't your question very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633092/efficiently-passing-custom-object-data-between-android-activities-mono-android) then?

Comment: check out my edit... maybe it helps you - else I'm sorry - don't know much about history... ehhhhm xamarin.

Comment: xamarin build androi and ios from c#, so I'm using the same code for the business and make the UI for android and after for IOS... But there are limitations :-/

Answer (score 1):

As you've specified you're using Monodroid, it looks like it's not straightforward. I did a quick search and found [this forum post](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/How-to-send-a-custom-Data-Class-to-next-Activity-td4805844.html)

Which listed the following solutions to this problem in Monodroid:

> Store the custom Object to be passed as a global variable somewhere, and just read it from your second activity

Which is a bit messy and bad practice, but would work.

Or

> serialize your class to a string and send the string to the second Activity

Which will  be a little more hard work, but better practice

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how to create a Parcelable class:

```
public class Person implements Parcelable { 
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
        // Get and Set methods

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
         return hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(surname);
        dest.writeString(email);
    }

 // We reconstruct the object reading from the Parcel data
    public Person(Parcel p) {
        name = p.readString();
        surname = p.readString();
        email = p.readString();
    }
    public Person() {}

   // We need to add a Creator

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<person> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<person>() {

    @Override
    public Person createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {  
       return new Person(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] newArray(int size) {  
       return new Person[size];
    }
};
```

Give a look [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/passing-data-between-activities.html) if you want to use Parcelable.

Comment: The OP has said he's using Monodroid, which is written in C#